# How strongly must a Mezuza be attached

Tags: halacha, mezuzah

If someone doesn't want to bang in their Mezuza so firmly that it will be hard to get it off in the event that it needs to be checked, or to replace it, can the Mezuza be attached to the doorpost without banging the nails in all the way, so that it still has some wiggle room? If so, how much wiggle room is allowed?

Can it be velcro'ed to the doorpost?

Comment: Strong enough that it doesn't fall off?

Comment: @Shokhet If you can show that that is all you need, it would make a good answer.

Comment: YEZ If I could I would....

Comment: I don't know about Velcro - but I have definitely heard of double sided adhesive tape being acceptable.

Comment: @Epicentre that's what we use on our metal door frames.

Comment: Workaround: consider screws.

Answer (score 4):

The Aruch Hashulchan in Yoreh Deah siman 289 siff 15 says even though one must use nails to affix the mezuzah, he thinks gluing the mezuzah with paper to the wall is good enough because its a solid connection to the wall, as opposed to making a small protrusion and resting the mezuzah on that, being that its not a 'chibur gamur'.