# May a mezuza be attached with screws rather than nails?

Tags: halacha, mezuzah

Although it is typical to use nails to secure a mezuza (e.g., [How strongly must a Mezuza be attached](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45701/how-strongly-must-a-mezuza-be-attached)), are screws acceptable?

Comment: So long as it’s affixed properly in place, why should it matter how it’s affixed?

Comment: I've known people who used double-sided tape.

Comment: What's the difference between a screw and a nail? Aren't they both just thin metal pegs that connect objects to each other? Will we also get a question about flat head or Phillips?

Comment: @DonielF  Nails are almost always mentioned in affixing a mezuza, screws almost never.  For example, this Chabad site mentions nails and glue but not screws. https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/278460/jewish/How-to-Affix-a-Mezuzah.htm#6. Certainly Chabad knows about screws.

Comment: I have always used screws since it is easier to take off for checking and putting back. I wasnt aware there was any problem. If someone comes up with one I will have to change.

Comment: @Yehuda The Mechaber says nothing about nails, only affixing. The Gemara discusses hanging it by a string from the lintel at the right height, not even attaching it to the doorpost after all.

Comment: Phillips all the way.

Comment: At the time the Talmud was written, screws were primarily used in screw presses for making wine or olive oil.  They weren't used as fasteners until 1500 or so.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in the Talmud ([Menachot 32-33](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Menachot.32b.9?lang=he&with=Tosafot&lang2=he)) and codified by the Tur ([Y"D 289](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tur%2C_Yoreh_Deah.289.1?lang=he&p2=Bach%2C_Yoreh_Deah.289.8&lang2=he)), a Mezuza must be affixed either in the doorpost or on the doorpost, and may not hang.

See the Bach (ibid) who brings the Mordechai who brings proofs that **it's sufficient** to use nails, since (as he proves) putting up a Mezuza does not require an artisan; every layman can do it.

Hanging is defined as being affixed by a single nail, so that it can swing, or fall over. Standing it on a shelf (or tiny protrusion) so that it can get knocked off is also considered hanging and invalid. Though the Bach seems to conclude that it's not invalid - it's just preferable to affix it such that it can't possibly fall or be knocked over.

Point being that going back to the original sources we see that "nails" were suggested, as being the easiest way to assure that the Mezuza affixed to the doorpost doesn't get knocked off.

There's no problem using methods that give the same or better assurance that it won't fall off. So screws are simply a better and even safer way to assure the mezuza doesn't get knocked (or ripped) off.

The question would be about glue, double-sided tape and other methods that would depend on various factors (like exposure to direct sunshine) if they have the same strength as nails to ensure the Mezuza can never fall or be knocked off the doorpost.

---

**ב"ח יורה דעה, רפ״ט:ח׳**

> א. וכיצד קובעה **יסמר אותה במסמרים** במזוזות הפתח וכו' כן כתב גם **הרמב"ם ספ"ה** ונראה שלמדו להורות כך מהך דבס"פ השואל דקאמר תלמודא גבי שוכר בית מחבירו דמקום **מזוזה כיון שאין בו מעשה אומן** השוכר עושהו שהרי אפשר הוא בגובתא דקניא ופירש"י שאפי' מקום מזוזה הוא אבן אין צריך מעשה אומן לנקוב בו סדק להניתה בתוכה דאפשר הוא בגובתא דקניא ותולה אותה עכ"ל ועל פירוש זה הקשו התוס' בפרק הקומץ (סוף מנחות דף ל"ב) מדאמר שמואל **תלאה במקל** פסולה ותירצו לא תלי ממש קאמר עכ"ל **ובמרדכי** **ה' קטנות** ע"ש רבינו שמשון מבואר התירוץ וז"ל י"ל יכניסנו בחלל הקנה ויקבענה בכותל וא"צ אומן עכ"ל נראה דר"ל דיכניסנו בחלל הקנה אורך הקנה כאורך מזוזה שבכתב כמנהג כל ישראל ואחר כן יקבענה בעץ או באבן שהדלת שוקף עליו דאף הוא קרוי מזוזה דהיינו **יסמר אותה בעץ או באבן במסמרים** וזהו שאמר ויקבענה בכותל כלומר במזוזת העץ או האבן שהיא בכותל אבל התוס' בפרק השואל כתבו וז"ל בגובתא דקניא מכאן נראה כמו שפירש"י במנחות שמניחין המזוזה מעומד לכן צריך גובתא דקניא **שלא תפול** אבל לפי' ר"ת שמניחין אותה מיושב כמו ס"ת מונח בארון ולא מעימד ובמנחות נמי עשאה כמין נגר פסולה היינו מעומד וכו' ואם כן גובתא דקניא למה לי וי"ל שלא תבלה מלחלוחית הכותל עכ"ל וצריך לבאר דהתוספות היו תופסים בפשיטית דלא תלי ממש קאמר מדקאמר שמואל בפ' הקומץ תלאה במקל פסולה אלא הכי קאמר דמעמיד גובתא דקניא ארוכה כגובה הפתח בתוך הפתח מן הקורה עד הקרקע ונותן המזוזה שבכתב בתוך אותו הקנה א"כ מכאן נראה שמניחין המזוזה מעומד לכך צריך גובתא דקניא **שלא תפול** כלומר אבל אם היה קובע דף קטן אורכו לרוחב מזוזת הפתח והיה מעמיד המזוזה שבכתב על הדף בלא גובתא דקניא **היה אפשר שתפול** אבל בגובתא דקניא כדפרישית הרי הוא קבועה בקניא מעומד ו**ליכא למיחש לנפילה** אבל לפר"ת שמניח אותה מיושב כו' קשה אם כן גובתא דקניא למה לי יניח המזוזה שבכתב כמו שהיא בלא גובתא דקניא על הדף הקטן כדאמרן ויניחנה מיושב כמו ס"ת מונח בארון ושוב ודאי לא יפול ותירצו שלא תבלה מלחלוחית הכותל כנ"ל לפרש דבור זה הסתום בעיני הלומדים והשתא לפ"ז מבואר **דאין צריך לקובעו במסמרים** בין לפירש"י בין לפר"ת אלא צריך לומר **דלמצוה מן המובחר כי היכי דלא ליתי לידי זלזול ע"י נפילה בחשש רחוק יסמר במסמרים** דהשתא ליכא חששא דנפילה כל עיקר אפי' בחשש רחוק ודו"ק. שוב מצאתי בירושלמי פ' בתרא דמגילה רבי בא בשם ר' יהודה ואפי' לא סמרו והא תני והוא שסמרו א"ר יוסי והוא שייחדו לכן עכ"ל נראה דכך פירושו דוקא כשהוא מייחד מזוזה זו לפתח זה צריך שיסמרו אבל אם אינה מייחדה אלא לפי שעה א"צ שיסמרו וז"ל לשם של בית מליון היו עושין כן בפולמסיות פי' כשהיו הולכין עם החיילות היו קובעין מזוזה לפי שעה ולא סמרו:‏